# How can I change my non-www to www while keeping subdirectories in url?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following in my root .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .html .htm
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ex-ample.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/es/(.*)$ http://es.example.com/$1
</IfModule>
```

This is my directory format so that it should read `www.example.com/directory1/wp/wp-admin`:

ROOT>directory1>wp>wp-admin

However, whenever I type `www.example.com/directory1/wp/wp-admin` in the search bar, it rewrites the url as `www.example.com/wp-admin`

Here is the .htaccess file in the `/wp` folder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /lisbonapartments.com/wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /lisbonapartments.com/wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What do I need to do to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: There's nothing in the `.htaccess` file(s) you've posted that would cause this. It's probably a WordPress configuration issue. (That is a very _specific_ redirect.) "whenever I type `www.example.com/directory1/wp/wp-admin`" - if that is what you're typing then it's not even using the non-www to www redirect you have in `.htaccess`.

Comment: `RewriteOptions inherit` - What directives are you inheriting?